# import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from “angularfire2/database”;

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angularfire2

**I'm getting an error that FirebaseListObservable has no imported member.
Also, it's saying that import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'; is declared but not use.
what's a way I can fix this issue.**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';


import { AngularFireAuth } from 'Angularfire2/auth';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';




@Injectable()
export class UserServiceProvider {

   items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

// this will be used to find out if a user has been loggged in then nav to another page
    success: boolean;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              private storage: Storage, private fbDb: AngularFireDatabase) {

              // This create a refrence to the users in the database
              this.items = fbDb.list('/users')

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using firebase 4.8.1 try downgrading to 4.8.0:

```
npm install firebase@4.8.0
```

Comment: I'm using firebase 4.80 and I'm still having this problem should I rerun an install thru the cli?

Comment: Ok check your package.json once and see what version of firebase is it showing is it :  "firebase": "^4.8.0"

Comment: and about the import *as firebase from 'firebase/app' its just an warning that you are not using the import. it should not be a reason to worry it wont cause errors

Comment: I'm using the firebase 4.8.0 without the ^ but I'm still having problems      
I followed these instructions.                                                                   Go back to firebase 4.8.0:

In your CLI with you project path type: npm uninstall firebase (which is 4.8.1)                                                          
then once fish uninstall, type: npm cache clear
-then type: npm install firebase@^4.8.0
-finally: Remove "firebase": "^4.8.1" in dependencies in package.json and Type "firebase": "4.8.0"
(Note: without ^). Save All and your problem will be solved! :)

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseListObservable is no longer used in later versions of angularfire2, try using AngularFireList instead:

```
    import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

And then:

```
    items: AngularFireList<any>;
```

Answer (score 0):

FirebaselistObservable is not used in the recent update.

Instead you need to import the following library:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

and declare items as:

```
items: Observable<firebase.User>;
```

Above implementation would resolve your error